# input no PHP com os campos preenchidos

Tags: input

Script em PHP.

Meu banco de dados tem 3 campos:

> id, nome, telefone.

Preciso atualizar os dados de 1 registro.

Na primeira página, solicito, por um input, o nome do registro a alterar, e um botão "Pesquisar" para localizar o registro a ser alterado.

Na segunda página coloco os 2 campos para edição:

```
$nome_g1 = isset($_GET["nome"])?$_GET["nome"]:"";
$arma1   = isset($_GET["telefone"  ])?$_GET["telefone"  ]:"";
```

Gostaria que os campos já viessem preenchidos com os dados do registro selecionado.

Exemplo:

1ª página digitei "Antonio", e o script encontrou o registro com o nome "Antônio" e o Telefone "99999.9999".

2ª página:

> Nome....: [Antônio]
>
> Telefone: [99999.9999]
>
> Botão:  [atualizar]

A dúvida é: como aparecerem os dados nos campos logo que entra na segunda página, antes da digitação, ou seja, na linha do "input"

Answer (score 1):

Basta por um `echo` no PHP devolvendo o valor no campo `value`:

Se for na parte em HTML

```
Nome: <input name="nome" value="<?php echo htmlentities( $nome ); ?>">
```

ou na parte em PHP:

```
echo 'Nome: <input name="nome" value="'.htmlentities( $nome ).'">';
```

Para campos como `select`:

```
<select name="estado">
   <option value="SP"<?php echo $estado=="SP"?' selected':''; ?>>
```

Mesma coisa para `radio` e `checkbox`, só trocar o selected pelo atributo HTML apropriado.

Obviamente que se for usar várias opções no select, pode ser mais prático uma função separada para isso, mas é só entender a lógica acima.

Comment: Funcionou perfeito, mas, não consegui montar o mesmo para "select" e "radio":
---
Estado:
<select name="estado_">
 <option value="MG" >Minas G</option>
 <option value="SP" >S paulo</option>
 <option value="RJ" >R Jan  </option>
</select>
---
<fieldset><legend> arma: </legend>
   <input type="radio" name="estado" value="MG" /><label for="MG">MG  &nbsp &nbsp </label>
   <input type="radio" name="estado" value="SP" /><label for="SP">SP  &nbsp &nbsp </label>
   <input type="radio" name="estado" value="RJ" /><label for="RJ">RJ   </label>
</fieldset>
---

Comment: Acrescentei na resposta, mas quando for assim, você tem que já colocar os detalhes todos direto na pergunta.

Comment: Não consegui montar para o radio e checkbox. Sou calouro.

Comment: Ai usa `checked` em vez de `selected`. Não que seja problema eu te dizer o que fazer, mas se aprender a ler documentação do HTML e pesquisar, fica muito mais fácil de vc aprender (senão, sempre vai estar copiando e colando, em vez de programar de verdade)

Comment: É o que mais estou fazendo!!!